# How can I use spring reactor (Flux) with Spring State Machine

Tags: flux, spring-statemachine

I want in an action of the state machine to write code that uses spring reactor. How can I return a result from the subscriber to the state machine?

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand what you're asking but most likely every attempt to use reactive libs with state machine would be hacks and probably not provide good results.

Originally we wanted to have reactor integration with 2.0.x but we had to postpone this work to 2.1.x and initial 2.x is now going to be a simple boot2 upgrade.

Comment: within an Action method i have code that calls a services that returns a flux. currently i have to call block so that i can return a value from the action, it would be nice to have deferedresult like in mvn